# How does the cat command (with no args) duplicate its stdin?

Tags: c, linux, bash, stdout, cat

I'm trying to understand how/why the `cat` command parses its stdin the way that it does.

When I set `cat`'s stdin to be "infile.txt", the stdin is simply written to stdout:

```
~$ echo foo bar test > infile.txt 
~$ cat < infile.txt
foo bar test
~$
```

This is as I would expect it. However, when I run cat with its stdin set to my (p)tty, stdin is duplicated to stdout until EOF is read:

```
~$ cat
foo bar test
foo bar test
input is duplicated
input is duplicated
^C
~$
```

For each pair:

- the first line is displayed as the user types. (this is NOT written to stdout/stderr)
- the second line is produced once the user presses `[enter]`. (this is written to stdout)

How is this possible? As I understand it, `sh` parses both of the above commands in such a way that `cat` is called with (argc=1, argv=["cat"]). So, the call to `cat` is the same. If this is the case, then why isn't the output duplicated in the `~$ cat < infile.txt` example?

As `cat` reads each character from its stdin from `infile.txt`, shouldn't it ALSO print out the read character (as it does int the simple `~$ cat` case)?

I've looked at this simple(ish) implementation [1] but it doesn't behave in the same way as ubuntu 18.04's cat. It doesn't print out the duplicated inputs as in the simple `~$ cat` example.

[1] https://gist.github.com/pete/665971#file-unix7-cat-c

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`cat` only outputs its input once. It's the terminal that also outputs user input.

You can, for example, disable terminal echo by typing

```
stty -echo
```

and then (blindly) start `cat` and start typing - no duplicate output.

Comment: This is a lot simpler than I was expecting. It's clear to me now that typed characters are not immediately made available to cat. I think that was the source of my confusion. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Basically `cat` works as follows:

```
while (block = read_block(input)) {
    write_block(block, output);
}
```

The block size depends on whether stdin is a tty or a file. When stdin comes from a tty, the input is line buffered otherwise block buffered.

Comment: I found another command `wc -c` which when used without any argument, opens a multiline editor, when I press enter it just goes to next line and nothing shows on output, do you know how I can use it without arguments?